# Why choose VSO over IaaS TFS 2013/15

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

I've been pouring over the Microsoft information and I'm finding it difficult to determine if there is any reason to support using On-Premise TFS 2015 or Infrastructure as a Service TFS 2015 instead of Visual Studio Online.

I can see that VSO is patched regularly. More frequently than our in-house processes would allow. In fact VSO looks appealing because I wouldn't have to go through those processes to keep it up to date.

Does anyone have experience with the true cost and maybe some gotchas associated with VSO and IaaS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a post a fre months ago on that very subject but:

http://nakedalm.com/benefits-visual-studio-online-enterprise/

- **Its more secure** - MS, while a biger target, spend hundreds of millions on security
- Better support & SLA - SAAS provides you with support and uptime for the application, not just the hardware.
- The experts are on it - if something goes wrong the developer who coded it is on the case.
- up to date - the 3 week feature drop is nothing to be sniffed at.
- Unlimited storage - TFS canbgrow quickly when you start using all the features, like Test Management. On VSO you pay for the users, not the disk space. And that disk space auto-grows ad infanitun.
- more flexible licencing - while MSDN is still supported you can only tranfer between people once every 3 months, and you need to pay per year, or three. VSO has a monthly model.